# Database call only works when evaluation is forced on a breakpoint

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am making a call to my SQL Server db but it never seems to return anything when I run it straight through or even when I step through after a break point.

I learned that if I go to a line after the call has been made but before the data has been used and view myRows.First() in a watch screen it won't show the data and says that "The function evaluation requires all threads to run". If I hit on the button to force the evaluation it returns the data and the rest of the program works just fine.

Is the a way to force that evaluation without having to do it manually in the debugger?

`myRows = _ctx.myTable.Where(mt => mt.name == myString);`

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

For immediate execution, you can use `ToList()`.

Longer Answer:

You need to use one of the many methods that triggers immediate query execution. Using a `foreach` loop will also enumerate the collection.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Manny, but I am using the following and it still isn't working 
`return myRows.Select(mr => new myModel()
            {
                name = mr.name
                
            }).ToList();`

Comment: Could you supply more code? What library are you using? SqlClient? EF?